# Eigen : co ordinates of a point in co ordinate frame A which is co ordinate frame B

Tags: eigen3, coordinate-transformation

Edit 1: Re phrased question.
I have 2 co ordinate frames A and B and a point Pt. Frame A is the base frame. Frame B is at some translation and rotation with respect to Frame A. Point Pt is fixed in frame B.
Every iteration The frame B is rotated along Z axis of Frame A by "DEG" degrees. I want to find out the co ordinates of the point Pt wrt to Frame A after each rotation.

This is similar to a ball stuck to a side of vertical rod. the rod rotates along z axis and the ball along with it. The rod here is the Frame A and the ball is the Frame B.

I have been using Eigen for this and have the static transform from A - B mapped to a variable.

```
// the frame A - Frame B translation and Rotation
Eigen::Vector3f trans = Eigen::Vector3f(xt,yt,zt);
Eigen::Quaternionf quat = Eigen::Quaternionf (xr,yr,zr,wr);
quat.normalize();
Eigen::Transform<float,3,Eigen::Affine> static_transform = Eigen::Translation<float,3>(trans) * quat;
// this the point in the frame A
Eigen::Vector3f newPoint (xp,yp,zp);
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question: Do you have 2 coordinate frames, or 2 coordinate frames per iteration (or does only frame `A` change)? And relative to what does `A` rotate? Also, is `Pt` fixed to every `B`, or just the first `B`? If `Pt` is fixed to `B` and `B` is fixed to `A`, then `Pt` is fixed to `A`.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, then it boils down to:

```
Vector3f p_in_B(...);
while(...) {
  // update static_transform
  Vector3f p_in_A = static_transform * p_in_B;
}
```

The last product is equivalent to:

```
p_in_A = static_transform.linear() * p_in_B + static_transform.translation();
```

Comment: You almost got it right. So the Point Pt in A should be
pt in A = (in place rotation from A - B  * translation from A-B ) * rotation by "DEG" * ( pt in B).
I am just not able to understand the right syntax for this.

Comment: So I have managed to get the x,y co ordinates using the code below. but all the 3D points are squished to one plane with z=0.  

`Eigen::Quaternion<float> quat;
            quat = Eigen::AngleAxis<float>(DEG, Eigen::Vector3f(0, 0, 1));
            Eigen::Transform<float, 3, Eigen::Affine> t = static_quat * Eigen::Translation<float, 3>(translation) *   current_angular_quat;
            Eigen::Vector3f newPoint (Pt_x,Pt_y,Pt_z);
            newPoint = t * newPoint;`

Comment: Note that the angles must be in radiant.

Comment: the angles are in radians. I think i kknow the problem is that i am using a 3x3 matrix for 3D when should be 4x3.